# Getting an error after starting Expo DevTools with 'npm start' command

Tags: react-native, npm, expo, npm-start

I just started learning React Native and am trying to setup the Expo DevTools, but I receive an error after a short while when I write the line '***npm start***' in the command prompt and the a tab starts up as 'http://localhost:19002/' in the browser. At first, it loads the page, then very shortly it becomes an empty black screen with an error prompted on the command line:
[Here is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orLtQ.png)(Using Windows 10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue. For anyone who encounters this issue, the solution that worked for me is to downgrade the version of the Node.js to 10.16.3